# Ag grid header row expand and collapse

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

We are using Ag-grid in our project. We have to implement expand/collapse functionality of Ag-grid at grid header level. When we click on collapse icon it will collapse all the grouped  nodes under this header and the vice versa for expand.

I have tried with anchor control click event by placing it on the first column of the grid and tried with the below code in my type script but getting error

> Can not read property foreachnode of undefined

How can i implement this?

```
public expandAll = () => {
    this.api.forEachNode((node: any) => {
        if (node.group) {
            node.setExpanded(false);
        }
    });
}
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where does the `this.api` come from? Could you add the snippet where it is initialized?

Comment: self.gridOptions =
        {
            onGridReady: this.onGridReady.bind(this), 
            suppressPropertyNamesCheck: true
           
        };                                                                                                                                        public onGridReady(params: any) {
        if (ViewContext.hasViewBeenDetached(this)) {
            return;
        }
        this.api = params.api;
        //this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
        this.gridReady.resolve(true);
    }

Comment: That line does nothing with `this.api`?

Comment: @MaartenDev  any suggestion please. this.api = params.api;

Comment: What does the api object look like? params sounds like props of a component. Did you check the parent component of this component to ensure the property value for api is provided?